# Substitute multiple names in a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, dynamic

I need to set multiple variables for more names, example @nom2 (@Real2), @nom3 (@Real3).

How can I do this without repeating all the code lines (Sum), where only the person name changes? I have a feeling it is with dynamic SQL, but to be honest I really don't know the way.

````
use Performance
go
declare @nom1 nvarchar(20)
declare @nom2 nvarchar(20)
declare @real1 int
set @nom1 = 'Ricardo'
set @nom2 = 'Pedro'
set @Real1 = (select(
sum (case when [SUPERVISOR] = @nom1 and [FAMILIA] = 'MEOFIBRA' and [EVENTO] = 'VB' then [QUANTIDADE] else 0 end) +
sum (case when [SUPERVISOR] = @nom1 and [FAMILIA] = 'MEOCOBRE' and [EVENTO] = 'VB' then [QUANTIDADE] else 0 end) +
sum (case when [SUPERVISOR] = @nom1 and [FAMILIA] = 'MEOSAT' and [EVENTO] = 'VB' then [QUANTIDADE] else 0 end)) from DOC```
````

Comment: Is this SQL Server or any other Database? Above code would not work as @nom2 is not defined. Is your set of `[FAMILIA]` , `[EVENTO]`  are also coming from a variables? 
Put the code for @nom2, @real2 as well.

Comment: this is sql server. i already edited and defined "nom2". those columns are from an already defined table, not coming from variables. the "real2" would be literally the same code, i could just copy  the code and change "nom1" to "nom2" and it would work but that's not really what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given info, I'd suggest:

Instead of defining variables, you can create a table and insert data to that and join that to the query as follows

```
Create table tNom (nom varchar(100))

insert into tNom values
('Ricardo'), ('Pedro')

select d.[SUPERVISOR], (
sum (case when [SUPERVISOR] = t.nom and [FAMILIA] = 'MEOFIBRA' and [EVENTO] = 'VB' then [QUANTIDADE] else 0 end) +
sum (case when [SUPERVISOR] = t.nom and [FAMILIA] = 'MEOCOBRE' and [EVENTO] = 'VB' then [QUANTIDADE] else 0 end) +
sum (case when [SUPERVISOR] = t.nom and [FAMILIA] = 'MEOSAT' and [EVENTO] = 'VB' then [QUANTIDADE] else 0 end)) as SumByNom
from DOC d
left join tNom t on d.[SUPERVISOR] = t.nom
Group by d.[SUPERVISOR]
```

If that table is no longer needed, you can create a temp table.
If you need a reference other than the **nom** you can have that extra column **RealCol** in tNom table and group by that as well and select **RealCol**, along with **nom**.

**Edit for new Requirement:**

```
drop table tNom
Create table tNom (nom varchar(100), SumColumn Real)

insert into tNom (nom) values 
('Ricardo'), ('Pedro')


Update t Set t.SumColumn = ColSum
From tNom t
inner join
(
    Select t.nom, 
        sum (case when [SUPERVISOR] = t.nom and [FAMILIA] = 'MEOFIBRA' and [EVENTO] = 'VB' then [QUANTIDADE] else 0 end) +
        sum (case when [SUPERVISOR] = t.nom and [FAMILIA] = 'MEOCOBRE' and [EVENTO] = 'VB' then [QUANTIDADE] else 0 end) +
        sum (case when [SUPERVISOR] = t.nom and [FAMILIA] = 'MEOSAT' and [EVENTO] = 'VB' then [QUANTIDADE] else 0 end) as ColSum
    from DOC d
    left join tNom t on d.[SUPERVISOR] = t.nom
    Group by t.nom
) q on q.nom = t.nom
```

Comment: yeah will try that way. thx! but wasn't it possible to this along the lines of dynamic sql?

Comment: It is possible, but cumbersome, error prone, non recommended

Comment: Hi @Srinika your code works perfect, but how can i insert the values of the sum in a new column of the table? the table itself only have the column names but the select shows the column names and their correspondent values.

Comment: @rafamaniac, To What table you need to get the data? Does that table has that column already?

Comment: the table you already created, but it only has the names. the values i wanted them to appear in the Real column "Create table tNom (nom varchar(100), Real)"

Comment: Ah Ok - I've already edited, assuming that you need that in Doc, I'll change it to Update tNom.

Comment: hi @Srinika it is giving me an error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Group' " can't find out why. i tried to put "select d.[supervisor](" after "t.SumColumn = " but not working properly too. i believe is just one step missing since the error is only on the group by.

Comment: Sorry, there was a bug in the query, I did in a rush. Please see now

Comment: it is exactly that, works as it should be, thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can define table variable and hold the names and update real values as given below. Below is untested code, as you have not provided sample values. But, you should get the idea.

```
DECLARE @NomReal TABLE(Nom nvarchar(20), Real int)

INSERT INTO @NomReal (Nom)
VALUES ('Ricardo'),('Pedro');

UPDATE n
SET Real = (
sum (case when [FAMILIA] = 'MEOFIBRA' and [EVENTO] = 'VB' then [QUANTIDADE] else 0 end) +
sum (case when [FAMILIA] = 'MEOCOBRE' and [EVENTO] = 'VB' then [QUANTIDADE] else 0 end) +
sum (case when [FAMILIA] = 'MEOSAT' and [EVENTO] = 'VB' then [QUANTIDADE] else 0 end))  
@NomReal AS n
INNER JOIN Doc as d
ON d.Supervisor = n.Nom
```

Now, you can get the Real value for every nom, by querying the table variable. if you want to persist this across batches, you can go for temp tables.

```sql
select Real from @NomReal Where nom = 'Pedro'
```